# Passive mode issue with vsftpd on Ubuntu (EC2)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vsftpd

I followed every guide but just can't login via ftp.

```
...
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
200 Switching to Binary mode.
local: 21 remote: 21
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||12028|)
550 Failed to open file.
221 Goodbye.
```

even had it in iptables:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:12000:12100
```

I have the `min` and `max` port set in `vsftpd.conf` to `12000-12100` and the same ports enabled via AWS console.

Comment: Is your EC2 instance running within a VPC?  If so, do the VPC Network ACLs allow those ports to be inbound (and outbound)?  Do the security groups associated with your EC2 instance allow those ports to be inbound?

Comment: Is using a different file transfer scheme acceptable? `scp` and `rsync`-over-`ssh` are two cross-platform commands that spring to mind.

Answer (score 3):

In your specific case, I see that you have an error 550 which makes me think there is a file permission problem.

In general, the most common cause for PASV mode to fail when vsftpd is running on EC2 is that vsftpd is telling the client to connect to ***the private IP address*** of the EC2 instance and the client cannot connect to it, for obvious reasons.

One possible solution is to assign an Elastic IP address to that instance and then tell vsftpd to announce itself with this public IP address (e.g. 1.2.3.4) by adding the following line to vsftpd.conf:

```
pasv_address=1.2.3.4
```

Let's take a step back and look at how PASV mode works:

- Client opens up a command channel by connecting to port 21 on the  public IP of the EC2 instance, which is mapped to the private IP of the instance by AWS itself.
- Client sends a PASV command to EC2 instance on the opened channel
- vsftpd knows that it's listening on the private IP address of the EC2 instance (the public IP of the instance is managed by AWS and it's not visible from within the instance) and sends a response to the Client which contains the private IP address of the instance and a random port between 12000 and 12100
- Client attempts to connect to the IP and port provided by vsftpd and fails

With `pasv_address` you force vsftpd to return the specified ip address when a PASV command is received, instead of trying to guess the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

as @Luca Gibelli said, it's mainly a file permission problem.

Could be better if you posting the file list and check what permissions has.

But I would answer this question in order to provide a small detail about the use `pasv_address` on EC2

If you using Elastic IP

```
pasv_address={your public IP address}
```

otherwise, maybe it's better to use

```
pasv_addr_resolve={your public domain or DNS}
```

take a look here: https://www.gosquared.com/blog/fix-ftp-passive-mode-problems-on-amazon-ec2-instances

Answer (score 0):

Some routers block regular ftp over the standard port. Switching to a non-standard port solved it for me.